# Suggestion to mock out a private method which is generating random values

Tags: java, hibernate, easymock

In DocInfoServiceImpl I have the following method which I'm trying to mock out using easymock. But am not clear on how I can return a docInfo object which is created using random uuid values(correlation and docfamily) and being returned from a private method ?

```
public void saveDocInfo(String docId)
        {
            **DocInfo docInfo = createDocInfo(docId);**
            LOG.debug("Attempting to persist the doc info object for docId [" + docId + "]");
            docInfoDao.save(docInfo);
            LOG.debug("Persisted the doc info object for docId [" + docId + "]");
        }

        private DocInfo createDocInfo(String docId)
        {
            final DocInfo docInfo = new DocInfo();
            docInfo.setId(docId);
            docInfo.setDocFamilyUuid(UUIDGenerator.getInstance().getUuidAsString());
            docInfo.setCorrelationId(UUIDGenerator.getInstance().getUuidAsString());
            return docInfo;
        }
```

And in my test i'm using, the mockDocInfoDao.save is being called in saveDocInfo of the service in 3rd line.

```
void testSave()
    {
        def String docId = 'I19292800fe1911e0a849005056932b99'
        mockDocInfoDao.save(expectedDocInfo)
        replay(mockDocInfoDao)

        docInfoServiceImpl.saveDocInfo(docId)

        verify(mockDocInfoDao)
    }
```

Comment: can you modify saveDocInfo to take the DocInfo object to save? Also, should this not be a method on DocInfo?

Comment: The way the logic is first the client will query using the dao if the docinfo object exists if not then it calls the save method to create one (can have any uuid  values) and save it

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test?

Answer (score 0):

Private methods are not meant to be tested as they are subject to change.

Using EasyMock, you would be checking if there is at least once invocation of save in saveDocInfo. So you could just instantiate DocInfo and pass it in testSave()

```
 void testSave()     {
     def String docId = 'I19292800fe1911e0a849005056932b99'
     mockDocInfoDao.save(new DocInfo())
     replay(mockDocInfoDao)

     docInfoServiceImpl.saveDocInfo(docId)

     verify(mockDocInfoDao)
 }
```

Comment: So what if a private method is used in 6 places within the class. Did you want to test it 6 times? did you want 6 tests to break when it has a problem? Or perhaps you might want to write a test ensure that your private method maintains the expected behavior and doesn't break other parts of the class... Code is code. Code that is re-used needs to be tested independently regardless of modifers. Usually the code is moved to a private method so that it can be re-used.

Comment: Just because a method is called 6 times, doesn't mean it'll result in 6 failures. The unit tests test the behaviour of a class via its public interface. It doesn't matter whether the failure is caused by a public method or a private method it calls but if it breaks the expectations of the test, then it should fail. If this is a problem, then it's a sign that the class should be refactored.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest flaw I can see in your code is the use of static methods.
It really hardens the testing task (see this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcT4yYu_TTs).

Can you update UUIDGenerator class somehow?
Maybe you could create an adapter class with an instance method calling this UUIDGenerator?